# AVCaptureSession camera fixed orientation with rotating interface

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

Assume the usual A, etc camera implementation, with a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer for preview. Now add another view on top with controls (and constraints). Now when the phone is rotated, the controls rotate in typical fashion, but I want the the preview unchanged, as in Apple's camera app. How can I keep the preview from rotating along with the controls?

This works but the animation is ugly:

```
 - (void) deviceOrientationDidChange
 {
     UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

     if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationUnknown || currentOrientation == orientation)
     {
         return;
     }

     currentOrientation = orientation;

     if (self.previewLayer)
     {
         if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
         {
             self.previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
             self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
         }
         else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
         {
             self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
             self.previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
         }
         else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
         {
             self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
             self.previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    _lowerWindow = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];
    _lowerWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _lowerWindow.hidden = NO;
    return YES;
}
```

then when you create the preview

```
[self setPreviewLayer:[[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:captureSession]];

[self.previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

CGRect layerRect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];
[self.previewLayer setBounds:layerRect];
[self.previewLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
                                           CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];

self.cameraView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[self.view bounds]];
[[self.cameraView layer] addSublayer:self.previewLayer];

AppDelegate* delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.lowerWindow insertSubview:self.cameraView belowSubview:self.view];
```

This uses a second UIWindow which will contain the preview layer; the original UIWindow created by the storyboard contains the UI and rotates while this one doesn't. The only drawback is the screen turns blank during rotation.

Only tested on iOS 8.